# Is there a way to link group of issues to one issue in JIRA?

Tags: jira, greenhopper

We would like to start using JIRA with GH for deployment/change management also. The proposed workflow for a Task/Story is as follows:
Backlog -> Open (added in the Sprint) -> In progress (coding) -> Resolved (code committed, work done) -> To Request for Change (Create a issue RFC-x which includes group of issues in the Sprint) ->

From here we track this RFC-x in new workflow: 
In test system -> Being tested -> Verified by QA -> Approved by Management -> Deployed to Production -> Verified by end user

Is there a way to link group of issues in one Sprint or Version with an issue easily?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using links is one approach

You can always link issues using the issue link feature provided by JIRA
http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Linking+Issues

There is a plugin which helps you track the links 
https://studio.plugins.atlassian.com/wiki/display/ILR/JIRA+Issue+Links+Report+Plugin
or the links hierarchy report
https://plugins.atlassian.com/plugin/details/5003

You can even take it a notch higher by automating state transitions between issues.
We described the concept of separating specifications and tasks here: http://www.idalko.com/display/WIC/Separation+of+specifications+and+tasks

Another approach would be to include your RFC-x as part of the sprint, and group all the issues which are related using a fix Version.
The request for change allows you to track the status of the deployment, in the context of a certain version without the need to manage the links between the issues and the RFC.

Comment: Thank you. Using link looks like the simplest approach for us. I created a filter based on the project and version. When linking, select the filter to choose multiple issues.

Comment: The link to idalko.com should now be: http://www.idalko.com/separation-of-specs-and-tasks.php

Comment: Thanks for providing a fix for this link.

Answer (score 2):

For grouping issues, you might want to take a look at the [Structure plugin](https://plugins.atlassian.com/plugin/details/34717) - it's still in early Beta though. Would love to hear feedback and feature requests.

Igor